# C# find the last item in a list where have a complete pair

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a global key logging application (not a virus but for some legitimate reasons), the application stores all keycode and the status in a List, e.g.:

```
public class KeyStatInfo {
    public int KeyCode;
    public bool IsDown;
    public KeyStatInfo(int keyCode, bool isDown) {
        KeyCode = keyCode;
        IsDown = isDown;
    }
}

private List<KeyStatInfo> _keyStats;
```

When a `KeyDown` event fired, the system will append an instance of `KeyStatInfo` with corresponding `KeyCode` and `IsDown` set to `true` to the `_keyStats` list, and while a `KeyUp` event appends an instance with `IsDown` of `false`. Note, as the nature of system events, a `KeyDown` events may fire more than once before firing the `KeyUp` event if the user holds the key down.

The system uses a `Timer` to store `_keyStats` (i.e., the buffer) to the database. However, before storing the buffer to the database, I need to redact some of the content, e.g., if no modifier keys are pressed, any `KeyCode` in the range of `Keys.A` to `Keys.Z` must be redacted to `Keys.A`, so the observer will only know the user typed a letter without knowing which letter it was.

The problem is that the `Timer` may kick in at any time, regardless if all the keys have released, therefore, I can only process the buffer to the last point that all keys are released.

I wonder if there are any efficient ways of finding the index of the last element in the buffer - possibly with Linq?

My current method is to scan through all the elements in the buffer, record all the states in a `Dictionary` and find the index in the `Dictionary` after all keys are iterated. This approach seems very inefficient and may slow the keyboard down when doing the redaction.

Sample:

```
_keyStats = new List<KeyStatInfo>();
_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(1, true)); // index = 0
_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(1, false)); // index = 1
// Expect: 1 - the index of the last element, so I know all keys are released

_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(1, true)); // index = 2
_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(1, true)); // index = 3
_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(2, true)); // index = 4
// Expect: 1 as well - the key 1 was pressed since index #2
// Note, key 1 was held since #2, and I need the last index before the first event
_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(1, false)); // index = 5
// Expect: 3 - although key 1 was released at index #5, key 2 was still unreleased since index #4
_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(2, false)); // index = 6
// Expect: 6 - all keys are released, return the index of the last element
```

---

To clarify, I need the last index in `_keyStats` that all `KeyCode` has closed (`IsDown` is `false`). Which is shown as the comments as above.

Comment: Please edit question and clarify your goal. What you want to get from _keyStats buffer (possibly with some linq query)?

Comment: @andrew Sorry for being a non-native speaker. I really don't know how to describe it better. Would you please kindly have a look at the example? The comments show my goal with explanations.

Comment: You're probably better off using [reactive programming](http://reactivex.io/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance does matter, then it is better to track state of all keys during the logging process. Possible solution:

1. Add new property to `KeyStatInfo`: `public bool AllKeysAreReleased { get; set; }`. This property indicates a state of all keys at moment of saving this stat element.
2. Make a dictionary `_keyState = new Dictionary<int, bool>()`. Value in dictionary shows if a key is released at the moment.
3. Each time user press or release a key, you update corresponding value in dictionary. Then calculate whole state: `var isAllKeysReleased = _keyState.Values.Aggregate(true, (acc, i) => acc && i);`. And pass that state to stats buffer: `_keyStats.Add(new KeyStatInfo(key, isDown, isAllKeysReleased));`
4. When you need to find an index of last stat element when all keys was released, you can use simple linq query: `_keyStats.Last(i => i.AllKeysAreReleased);`

Comment: Good idea! Thanks! But I'm still trying to not adding new variables - unless the performance is below acceptance.